# No Supporting Files directory in a Xcode Cordova project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, cordova

I need to integrate the phonegap BarcodeScanner plugin with my iOS6.1 project. To add the plugin I need to do the following:

> In the Supporting Files directory of your project, add a new plugin by
>   editing the file Cordova.plist and in the Plugins dictionary adding
>   the following key/value pair:    key:
>   org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner    value: CDVBarcodeScanner

But the problem is that I don't have a "Supporting Files" directory in my project, or at least I couldn't find one.

[Link to the plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner)

I was able to successfully run the app on a 6.1 iOS simulator and on a device.

**Xcode version**: 4.6.3

**Phonegap**: 2.9

**OS X**: 10.7.5

Here is my project in xCode:

[image]

I'm fairly new to both Phonegap and Apple devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't make any different if it is in "Supporting File" or not. It all gets linked in the same way. If it make you feel better you can create the missing group in your project and put it in there, just to tidy things up, but t really won't make any difference as you have seen by it working.

Hope this helps!